# Importing rules and data from different models in yii

Tags: php, yii

How can i pull data from different tables(models) into view in `yii`. actually i done this with `loadModel` method. but my question is how can we import the rules into the view too. Here comes my scenario 
I have a `User` model and `Profile` model. The `User` model contains username and password and `Profile` model contains userid,name,address etc. so in my profile edit view i need all these data with the rules, username-unique,password,confirm pasword-required, etc., i can implement the required rule to all these, but i dunno how to import the table related rules like unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically this is a form that takes in two models and displays that data for you to edit and submit.

Simply make the render call to your view and pass both the models. e.g. `$this->render('aview', array('model1'=>$model1, 'model2'=>$model2));`

Get your view to display the form elements based upon these models. 
When you submit simply create new objects for respective models and populate them with the data received. e.g.

```
$model1 = new model1;
$model1=>id = id; //id received from the form submit. 
...............
```

Once you have the models populated you can call `validate()` on each of them to figure out if the data is according to your rules. If it is you proceed otherwise you display error. I hope this helps unless I missed something in your question.

Comment: LET ME TRY.. THANKS FOR YOUR REPLY MR. @Orlymee